# Stuck inserting rows from a file into Database

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, odbc

I want to insert rows from excel sheet into SQL database using java or JSP. Initially I have connected both the database using ODBC. But I want to take an excel file as input from user. For this I created a file browser and upload the file.

1. How can I connect the uploaded file with ODBC connection?
2. How can I query the uploaded file?

If I use Apache POI to parse Excel file, I will get column names and that also get inserted. How can I avoid this?

a) How can I insert the rows with particular column name, not from column number?

Please provide me the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

1) How can i connect the uploaded file with ODBC connection?

You will have to write a service to map excel to DB if thats what you are asking?

Comment: yes... using DSN we can do that... but how to connect uploaded file with ODBC?

Comment: you can save the excel to a location on the server and then 

Class.forName( "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" );
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=C:/database.xls; readOnly= false");

do this. If that is what you are asking? But if you are already parsing using POI you do have data in the JAVA pojos with you all you have do to is SQL insert. I think I am not getting your question

Comment: It is the excel file.. This will basically be the absolute location of where the excel file is. So its like Java connects to a data source (this data source is the excel file)

Comment: how to know the how many rows are there before querying the Excel sheet???becaues i can't say i<12
for this ..
Sheet.rows will return you RowRecordsAggregate which contains methods getFirstRowNum(), getIterator(), getLastRowNum() etc..

Comment: SELECT COUNT should be able to say how many rows/records it is.

Comment: @Anish Mohile  this is not taking the browsed file as input. Instead its creating one more excel file without contents.

Comment: you have to write the uploaded file to it .... if that is what you are trying to do? What is your exact flow?
Upload Excel --- > parse using POI ----> put parsed values in database??? is it?

Comment: @Anish Mohile- upload excel file->Take that file as input-> Insert rows into Sql Database. this is what am trying to do.

Comment: so why do you need the above example? for connecting to the excel file.... just passin the input excel file to APache POI ir JXL and parse it. store the data into your objects and fire inserts on the DB...

Answer (score 0):

To get the values from the excel file , you should use Apache POI.
And the solution to the problem that column names are also inserted is :

If the column names are in row 1  , then start a loop from 1 instead of 10.

```
int i=1;
do{
   {
  HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(i);                   
  HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.getCell((short) 0);
  String a1Val = cellA1.getStringCellValue().toString();
  System.out.println(a1Val);
  i++;
  // And if you want to enter this value in sql database , write a odbc connection and  insert query to sql database.
}
}while(a1val.!equals("");
```

Comment: how to know the how many rows are there before querying the Excel sheet???becaues i can't say i<12...

Comment: I have edited the code. Suppose you have 25 rows of data.Then this code will run till 26th row.And since it will contain no value it will exit from the loop.